# CSS difference in firefox vs chrome

Tags: css

Why is chrome putting my menu items out of borders?

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

```
<td style="width: 50%; text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom; word-spacing: 20px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
<a href="?lang=ee"><img src="/ikoonid/ee.png"></a> <a style="margin-left: 1px;" href="?lang=en"><img src="/ikoonid/en.png"></a>
<a class="active" href="/">HOME</a>
<a  href="/games">GAMES</a>
<a  href="/search">SEARCH</a>
</td>
```

Comment: try adding overflow: visible ?

Comment: suggestion: show us the HTML code that the browser sees, not the PHP code. The PHP is irrelevant to the question and gets in the way of seeing what the problem is with the actual HTML. Go to "View source" in the browser, and paste it from there.

Comment: Horrible code snippet, please post a clean snippet that doesnt require PHP.

Comment: Does it help if you use a "reset CSS" stylesheet, like this one? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Sorry guys, corrected it.

Comment: Why are you using tables for your layout?

Comment: Can you give us enough HTML to actually reproduce what you show in those images?